# how to extract strings and create varying number of columns with the extracted values?

Tags: r

I have the following list of file paths. The data folder has sub folders with names as ID and each subfolder contains data files.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

paths <- c(
  "data/A101/usage.xlsx",
  "data/A101/cost.xls",
  "data/A101/A101 cost-1.csv",
  "data/B202/B202 data.csv",
  "data/B202/cost1.xlsx",
  "data/C303/usage1.xls",
  "data/D404/cost1.csv",
  "data/D404/D404 data1.xlsx",
  "data/E/E data1.csv"
)
```

I want to create a data frame that looks like this: `site_id` from the names of sub folders, `file_name_1` ... `file_name_n` with the extracted file names from each folder. `file_name_1` should contain all names of the first files from each site, `file_name_2` should contain all of the 2nd extracted file names (if exists), and so on.

```
df <- data.frame(
  site_id = unique(str_extract(paths, "[A-D]\\d+|E")),
  file_name_1 = c("usage.xlsx", "B202 data.csv", "usage1.xls", "cost1.csv", "data1.csv"),
  file_name_2 = c("cost.xls", "cost1.xlsx", NA, "D404 data1.xlsx", NA),
  file_name_3 = c("A101 cost-1.csv", NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

And I have tried the following:

```
test <- data.frame(
  site_id = str_extract(paths, "[A-D]\\d+|E"),
  file_name = str_extract(paths, "[^\\/]+$")
  ) %>%
  gather(key=key, value=value, -site_id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = "site_id",
    names_from = key,
    values_from = value,
    names_glue = "{key}_{seq_along({key})}",
    values_fn = list
  )
View(test)
```

[image]

The result has only one column with the file names combined into a vector. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
df <- data.frame(paths=paths) %>% 
separate(paths, into = c('new','site_id', 'file'), sep = '/') %>% 
  mutate(row=paste0('file_name_',row_number()),
         .by=site_id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = site_id, names_from = row,values_from = file)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  site_id file_name_1   file_name_2     file_name_3    
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>           <chr>          
1 A101    usage.xlsx    cost.xls        A101 cost-1.csv
2 B202    B202 data.csv cost1.xlsx      <NA>           
3 C303    usage1.xls    <NA>            <NA>           
4 D404    cost1.csv     D404 data1.xlsx <NA>           
5 E       E data1.csv   <NA>            <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `group_by` and `seq`.

```
as_tibble(gsub(pattern = "data/","",paths)) %>% 
  separate(value,into = c("site_id","file_name"),sep = "/") %>%
  mutate(file = seq(n()),.by=site_id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = site_id,names_from=file,
              values_from = file_name,
              names_prefix = "file_name_")
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   site_id [5]
  site_id file_name_1   file_name_2     file_name_3    
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>           <chr>          
1 A101    usage.xlsx    cost.xls        A101 cost-1.csv
2 B202    B202 data.csv cost1.xlsx      NA             
3 C303    usage1.xls    NA              NA             
4 D404    cost1.csv     D404 data1.xlsx NA             
5 E       E data1.csv   NA              NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `aggregate` to do the grouping, then `unnest_wider` to get the desired separation

```
library(tidyr)

aggregate(. ~ site_id, setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  strsplit(paths, "/"))[,2:3]), c("site_id", "file_name")), "c") |> 
  unnest_wider(file_name, names_sep="_")
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  site_id file_name_1   file_name_2     file_name_3    
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>           <chr>          
1 A101    usage.xlsx    cost.xls        A101 cost-1.csv
2 B202    B202 data.csv cost1.xlsx      NA             
3 C303    usage1.xls    NA              NA             
4 D404    cost1.csv     D404 data1.xlsx NA             
5 E       E data1.csv   NA              NA
```